# Looping backwards through highest order bits in a number

Tags: python, optimization, set, bit-manipulation

I have a function that receives an integer and returns a set that consists of powers of 2, sum of which equals the input value:

```
def bin_set(n):
    b = set()
    while n:
        hbit = 1 << n.bit_length()-1
        b.add(hbit)
        n -= hbit
    return b
```

So I calculate the highest bit of the number and add it to the set, but what value of `n` should I send to the next iteration of the loop? I used `n = n-hbit` because of the `while`'s condition and it somehow works, but I'm pretty sure that's a wrong approach.

Is there a different way to do it, maybe with a different loop and no logarithms/bit twiddling/bit_length() or is this the only approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach works just fine; you are removing the detected bit from `n` with subtraction until you removed all bits. As a result, the `n.bit_length()` result also decreases.

Instead of subtraction, you could use XOR (the `^` operator) to clear the high bit:

```
def bin_set(n):
    b = set()
    while n:
        hbit = 1 << n.bit_length() - 1
        b.add(hbit)
        n ^= hbit
    return b
```

A different approach would be to right-shift the high bit rather than altering `n`:

```
def bin_set(n):
    b = set()
    hbit = 1 << n.bit_length() - 1
    while hbit:
        if n & hbit:  # the high bit is set
            b.add(hbit)
        hbit >>= 1
    return b
```

but this actually does more tests!

Your version only loops as many times as there are bits set in `n` but does calculate the bit-count each iteration, while the above version loops `n.bit_length()` times. `int.bit_length()` takes O(N) average time to calculate the bit length, so yours takes O(KN) time to produce the set of K values from N bits, shifting the high bit takes O(N) time.

That makes my version better asymptotically, but because the `int.bit_length()` method does the work in C and reduces the loop to just one loop iteration per 4 bits it is not as bad as it sounds. You need *humongous* numbers before you'd start seeing mine win.

Comment: Thanks, the thought of using XOR to unset the bit didn't occur to me somehow, I like it much better! I actually tested the second loop and it seems to me there's always at least one more iteration involved, though I can't think of a good worst-case.

Comment: @cbq: worst-case: a very large integer with all bits set. `19342813113834066795298815` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something called a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which is a very concise way to create them.

```
def bin_set(n):
    return {1 << p for p in xrange(n.bit_length()-1, -1, -1) if n & 1 << p}

print bin_set(0)   # --> set([])          
print bin_set(10)  # --> set([8, 2])      
print bin_set(12)  # --> set([8, 4])      
print bin_set(15)  # --> set([8, 1, 2, 4])
```